# How can I keep my program from getting this segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a program that is getting a segmentation fault. The program is a magic square program and asks users for the size of a square (a matrix) and then for the numbers of the square by row. I am using a pointer to point to the array in the declareArray function to reference where it is declared in the main function. I want to keep the pointer in order to practice using them, even though I know I can make the program work without pointers. I think the pointer is the problem here but I cant find what I am doing wrong with it.

here is the code:

```
int main(void)
{
        int *arr[SIZE][SIZE] = "\0";
        declareArray(&arr);
        declareArray();

return 0;
}
        //main logic
int declareArray(int *arr[SIZE][SIZE])
{
        //variables
        int rowNumber = 0;
        int dimension = 0;
        //int arr[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};
        int row, col;
        int sum, sum1, sum2;
        int flag = 0;

        //ask for input of squares
        printf("Please enter the dimension of the square: ");
        //makes sure the size is between 1 and 15 for the dimension of the square
        if(scanf("%d", &dimension) != 1 || dimension >= 15 || dimension < 1)
        {
                printf("invalid input\n");
                return 1;
        }
        //enter the data

        //array rows
        for(row = 0; row < dimension; ++row)
        {
                printf("Please enter the data for row %d: ", ++rowNumber);
                //array columns
                        for(col = 0; col < dimension; ++col)
                        {
                                //store the user input
                                scanf("%2d", &*arr[row][col]);
                        }
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("Here is the square");
        printf("\n");
        //print the square

        //array rows
        for(row = 0; row < dimension; ++row)
        {
                //array columns
                for(col = 0; col < dimension; ++col)
                {
                        printf("%d", *arr[row][col]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

 //Checks Sum of diagonal elements
   sum = 0;
   for (row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      for (col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
         if (row == col)
            sum = sum + *arr[row][col];
      }
   }

   //Checks Sum of Rows
   for (row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      sum1 = 0;
      for (col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
         sum1 = sum1 + *arr[row][col];
      }
      if (sum == sum1)
         flag = 1;
      else {
         flag = 0;
         break;
      }
   }

   //Checks sum of Columns
   for (row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      sum2 = 0;
      for (col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
         sum2 = sum2 + *arr[col][row];
      }
      if (sum == sum2)
         flag = 1;
      else {
         flag = 0;
         break;
      }
   }
   //if the sums match, it will print a success message with the constant
   //if the sums dont match, a fail message will appear
   if (flag == 1)
      printf("\nTHE SQUARE IS A MAGIC SQUARE WITH A CONSTANT OF %d \n", sum);
   else
      printf("\nThe Square is not a magic square \n");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: This initialization `int *arr[SIZE][SIZE] = "\0";` doesn't seem right. It's incorrect for multiple reasons. This syntax `&*arr[row][col]` is also strange, did you want to write `arr[row][col]`? Enable compiler warnings and start from there. Read about pointers and be sure to understand them.

Comment: `declareArray(&arr); declareArray();` --> `declareArray(arr);`

Comment: Start by enabling compiler warnings, and fix them before posting questions.  For instance, initializing `arr` with a string makes no sense.

Comment: `scanf("%2d", &*arr[row][col]);` : `arr[row][col]` doesn't point to area of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see few issues here

```
         int *arr[SIZE][SIZE] = "\0"; // this wont compile
         declareArray(&arr); // needless
         declareArray();
--- 
         int arr[SIZE][SIZE] = {};
         declareArray(arr);
         //declareArray();
```

Declare function

```
 int declareArray(int *arr[SIZE][SIZE]) // because function call changed
---
 int declareArray(int arr[SIZE][SIZE])
```

finally in `printf` and `scanf` remove the `*` operator not needed anymore

as in

```
    scanf("%2d", &*arr[row][col]); // remove *
---
    scanf("%2d", &arr[row][col]);

    printf("%d", *arr[row][col]);  // remove *
---
    printf("%d", arr[row][col]);

    sum = sum + *arr[row][col];  // remove *
---
    sum = sum + arr[row][col];
```

Comment: thanks so much! I should have realized I needed to get rid of those. Im still new to pointers

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that when you declare an array, the name of the array is a pointer to the first element of the array:

   ```
   &arr[0] == arr.
   ```
2. The argument passed to the declareArray function is an array of **pointers** to integers, therefore the space needed for the pointers was allocated yet the space for the actual ints was not, so when you are trying to scan an integer to the address pointed to by `arr[row][col]`, you are trying to write to the address that it holds, 0 in your case , and address 0 is most likely out of the data segment, hence the segment_fault.

What should you do then?

Allocate the space needed with `malloc()`, assign the address returned to `arr[row][col]` and then `scanf()` as shown below, or alternatively, and quite simpler and better use an int array and simply assign the integer to `arr[row][col]` as shown in the answer above

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 15

int declareArray(int * arr[SIZE][SIZE]);

int main(void)
{
    int * arr[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};
    declareArray(arr);

    return 0;
}
    //main logic
int declareArray(int * arr[SIZE][SIZE])
   {
    //variables
    int rowNumber = 0;
    int dimension = 0;
    int row, col;
    int sum, sum1, sum2;
    int flag = 0;
    int * myVal;
    //ask for input of squares
    printf("Please enter the dimension of the square: ");
    //makes sure the size is between 1 and 15 for the dimension of the square
    if(scanf("%d", &dimension) != 1 || dimension >= 15 || dimension < 1)
    {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
    }
    //enter the data

    //array rows
    for(row = 0; row < dimension; ++row)
    {
            printf("Please enter the data for row %d: ", ++rowNumber);
            //array columns
                    for(col = 0; col < dimension; ++col)
                    {
                            printf("insert data to row %d col %d: ", rowNumber, col+1);                                
                            arr[row][col] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
                            scanf("%2d", arr[row][col] );
                    }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Here is the square");
    printf("\n");
    //print the square

    //array rows
    for(row = 0; row < dimension; ++row)
    {
            //array columns
            for(col = 0; col < dimension; ++col)
            {
                    printf("%d", *arr[row][col]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

 //Checks Sum of diagonal elements
   sum = 0;
   for (row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      for (col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
        if (row == col)
            sum = sum + *arr[row][col];
      }
   }

      //Checks Sum of Rows
      for (row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      sum1 = 0;
      for (col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
         sum1 = sum1 + *arr[row][col];
      }
      if (sum == sum1)
         flag = 1;
      else {
         flag = 0;
         break;
      }
   }

   //Checks sum of Columns
   for (row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      sum2 = 0;
      for (col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
         sum2 = sum2 + *arr[col][row];
      }
      if (sum == sum2)
         flag = 1;
      else {
         flag = 0;
         break;
      }
    }
   //if the sums match, it will print a success message with the constant
   //if the sums dont match, a fail message will appear
   if (flag == 1)
      printf("\nTHE SQUARE IS A MAGIC SQUARE WITH A CONSTANT OF %d \n", sum);
   else
      printf("\nThe Square is not a magic square \n");

 return 0;
}
```